# MacOS 12.1 cannot find my brew install of GNU binutils

Tags: macos, homebrew, binutils

I want to use GNU binutils to inspect an executable on MacOS 12.1. I did a

```
% brew install binutils
```

and it seemed to go fine. First I tried just a

```
% readelf <executable>
```

but was given:

```
zsh: command not found: readelf
```

Then I tried checking on binutils itself:

```
% binutils -v
```

which gave me

```
zsh: command not found: binutils
```

I tried adding both

```
/usr/local/opt/binutils
```

and

```
/usr/local/Cellar/binutils
```

to my $PATH and restarting zsh. The filepaths were in my $PATH, and homebrew had put 'binutils' in the expected locations. But

```
% binutils -v
```

still gives me

```
zsh: command not found: binutils
```

.
Has anyone gotten binutils to work on Mac? What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

You needd to add :

```
/usr/local/opt/binutils/bin
```

Comment: The question doesn't give any environment info, if your mac is M1 based and homebrew is native, then the corresponding path will be `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/binutils/2.37/bin`(change 2.37 to the version of binutils you installed)

Comment: Use this path on Mac M1 `/opt/homebrew/opt/binutils/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

##### The path `/usr/local/opt/binutils/bin` should be added to your `PATH` environment variable.

You probably didn't notice the output from `brew install binutils`:

> binutils is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into
> /usr/local, because Apple's CLT provides the same tools.
>
> If you need to have binutils first in your PATH, run:   echo 'export
> PATH="/usr/local/opt/binutils/bin:$PATH"' >>
> /Users/ipellegrini/.bash_profile
>
> For compilers to find binutils you may need to set:   export
> LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/binutils/lib"   export
> CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/binutils/include"

So should be enough to:

- ⤵️
  run `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/binutils/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile` in order to add the `bin` folder to `PATH`, automatically, every time you open a new command-line shell.
- close the current shell and open a new one, for triggering the `.bash_profile` and making the command available for use.
- run `which readelf` to ensure that your desired command is found & reachable

*Enjoy*

Answer (score 0):

Check if Xcode is installed or not:

```
$ gcc --version

$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"

$ brew doctor

$ brew update
```

Answer (score 0):

Same error message when building micro-ROS packages with the platformio CLI for vscode, for some reason platoformio identifies all newer macos versions as being ARM machines and will search for binutils in the default ARM prefix, not the x86 prefix. Creating the expected ARM path and a symlink to the x86 prefix fixes this and will allow code to build, but will break your brew install until the ARM prefix is deleted.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).